# How to configure Ubuntu as router in Vagrant

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ip, vagrant, router

I'm trying to configure a simple network structure using Vagrant as depicted in the following figure:

[image]

As you can see I aim to simulate a hacker attack which goes from `attacker` through `router` and reaches `victim`, but that's not important for the problem I'm struggling with.

This is my Vagrantfile so far (VritualBox is used as provider):

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define "router" do |router|
    router.vm.box = "hashicorp/bionic64"

    router.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.232.1"
    router.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.248.1"

    router.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
      sudo apt-get install traceroute
      echo -e "\nnet.ipv4.ip_forward=1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
    SHELL
    router.vm.provision :reload
  end

  config.vm.define "attacker" do |attacker|
    attacker.vm.box = "hashicorp/bionic64"

    attacker.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.232.2"

    attacker.vm.provision "shell",
      inline: "sudo apt-get install traceroute"
    attacker.vm.provision "shell",
      run: "always",
      inline: "sudo route add default gw 192.168.232.1"
  end

  config.vm.define "victim" do |victim|
    victim.vm.box = "hashicorp/bionic64"

    victim.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.248.2"

    victim.vm.provision "shell",
      inline: "sudo apt-get install traceroute"
    victim.vm.provision "shell",
      run: "always",
      inline: "sudo route add default gw 192.168.248.1"
  end

end
```

Please note that I am using the `vagrant-reload` plugin so you have to install it before doing `vagrant up`

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-reload
```

What the Vagrantfile does:

- set the `net.ipv4.ip_forward` to `1` in `router` machine
- add default gateway 192.168.232.1 to `attacker` machine
- add default gateway 192.168.248.1 to `victim` machine

Just to confirm that enabling `net.ipv4.ip_forward` worked on `router`:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

Unfortunately, I can't get it to work. When I try to `ping 192.168.248.2` from the `attacker` machine then I get no response. Output from `traceroute` seems to be going through the `router` machine but it stucks there and never reaches `victim`:

```
traceroute to 192.168.248.2 (192.168.248.2), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  legion (192.168.232.1)  0.300 ms  0.454 ms  0.439 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
```

Output from `netstat -r` on `attacker` machine:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         legion          0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth1
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
_gateway        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.232.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
```

I don't know why the new gateway I have added is named `legion` but I assume it's somehow taken from my laptop hostname (it's Lenovo Legion named as `legion`).

Output from `netstat -r` on `victim` machine:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         legion          0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth1
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
_gateway        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.248.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
```

Output from `netstat -r` on `router` machine:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
_gateway        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.232.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
192.168.248.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth2
```

Output from `ifconfig` on `attacker` machine:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:febb:1475  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:bb:14:75  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1271  bytes 129981 (129.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 926  bytes 141073 (141.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.232.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.232.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe5f:4829  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:5f:48:29  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 20  bytes 1704 (1.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 137  bytes 10188 (10.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 16  bytes 1628 (1.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 16  bytes 1628 (1.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Output from `ifconfig` on `victim` machine:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:febb:1475  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:bb:14:75  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 973  bytes 101812 (101.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 725  bytes 111966 (111.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.248.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.248.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe98:9693  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:98:96:93  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 6  bytes 486 (486.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 38  bytes 2812 (2.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 44  bytes 3574 (3.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 44  bytes 3574 (3.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Output from `ifconfig` on `router` machine:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:febb:1475  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:bb:14:75  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1866  bytes 164707 (164.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1301  bytes 165459 (165.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.232.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.232.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe90:2720  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:90:27:20  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1  bytes 60 (60.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 34  bytes 2466 (2.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.248.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.248.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe3b:238b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:3b:23:8b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2  bytes 120 (120.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 34  bytes 2466 (2.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 10  bytes 714 (714.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10  bytes 714 (714.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Do you have any ideas on what could be wrong here? Maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a redundant default gateway on `victim` and `attacker` called `_gateway`. You should delete it and leave only the one going to the router via `eth1` interface.

Comment: It worked! Seems that indeed there was a conflict between `_gateway` and `legion` because after deleting `_gateway` (and waiting like a couple of minutes for some reason) I'm able to ping the other subnet :D

Answer (score 2):

While the answer from `@thejazzroot` clearly pointed the root cause of my problem, it was not everything I had to do to make it work. For some reason, I was unable to ping `victim` from `attacker` (and the other way round) until I pinged one of those machines from `router`.

That was strange. Why would the network start working only after machines pinged each other? Now I've found an answer: `vagrant` automatically assigns host machine with the `.1` IP in each subnet (so in my case it was `192.168.232.1` and `192.168.248.1`). Unluckily, those are exactly the same IPs I assigned to my `router` VM and which `attacker`/`victim` machines have set as their gateways! So there were 2 machines with the very same IPs assigned and it seems that when `attacker`/`victim` was pinged from `router` then it somehow chose `router` over `legion`. Now it also makes sense where the `legion` name came from in the output of `netstat -r`.

**TL;DR** 
I've changed the `router` IPs in both subnets because there was a conflict with IPs which `vagrant` automatically assignes to the host machine:

```
192.168.232.1 -> 192.168.232.10
192.168.248.1 -> 192.168.248.10
```

In case someone is looking for the full solution, I'm posting my final Vagrantfile here:

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define "attacker" do |attacker|
    attacker.vm.box = "hashicorp/bionic64"
    
    attacker.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.232.2"
    
    attacker.vm.provision "shell",
      run: "always",
      inline: <<-SHELL
        ip route delete default
        ip route add default via 192.168.232.1
      SHELL
  end

  config.vm.define "victim" do |victim|
    victim.vm.box = "hashicorp/bionic64"
    
    victim.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.248.2"
    
    victim.vm.provision "shell",
      run: "always",
      inline: <<-SHELL
        ip route delete default
        ip route add default via 192.168.248.1
      SHELL
  end

  config.vm.define "router" do |router|
    router.vm.box = "hashicorp/bionic64"
    
    router.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.232.1"
    router.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.248.1"
    
    router.vm.provision "shell",
      inline: <<-SHELL
        echo -e "\nnet.ipv4.ip_forward=1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
        sysctl -p
      SHELL
  end
end
```